# Apache breaks when virtualhost is set to IP instead of wildcard

Tags: virtualbox, apache-http-server, ip-address, virtual-host

I have a VirtualBox with Ubuntu 20.04.01 running on it and I am trying to install a free admin panel called Froxlor (froxlor.org). I've successfully done everything except figuring out the virtualhosts and forwarding some non-imperative ports (ftp/sftp, ssh, etc.). I already have a Let's Encrypt certificate I got from Certbot and I originally installed it to the default virtualhost and then later specified it in all the Froxlor settings so Froxlor would add it to its own virtualhost. My goal is to make it so that the Froxlor-created virtualhost has the right settings to run my website without help from another custom file. That way I can control every aspect of my system from Froxlor and not from the command line. Currently, my public IP address is 64.53.213.26 and my private IP address is 192.168.1.39. I have a domain connected to the public IP called drewssite.us.to (feel free to visit).

Everything works fine on the default virtualhost which is a wildcard, but it doesnt work on the Froxlor-created one, where instead of a wildcard it is 64.53.213.26. When I load the page on Firefox using the Froxlor virtualhost it gives the error SSL_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG. When I edit the file and change the address to a wildcard,  it works. Unfortunately, Froxlor automatically checks the config files every minute and reverts my changes, and it doesn't allow wildcards in its settings, so I can't just tell Froxlor to make the file what I want. I know there has to be another solution out there because a wildcard means everything, so if it works, then something else must too because that's what the wildcard is using to make it work.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me you should be binding your internal IP address, not the external one. I'm assuming here that the VM host or some other external router/device is doing nat and the external IP does not appear in your VM.

Comment: The way by network is set up is that the VM is using bridged mode so it appears that the MAC address of my computer has two devices attached. I've forwarded the IP of the VM device so port 80 and 443 are forwarded to the public IP. I am using some other things that requires other ports, but as of today those aren't forwarded.

Comment: I don't understand your comment and I suspect you are conflating terms and network layers.  Does ip addr show / ifconfig on the web server specifically mention  64.53.213.26?

Comment: No, ip addr shows my private IP 192.168.1.39. The public IP is only on the router which is doing port forwarding.

Comment: That being the case on Apache you need to associate the Internal IP address with the cert - Apache doesn't know of the external IP (and doesn't need to).

Comment: Oh, I see. You were right the router is doing Nat (it just looks like port forwarding) I thought if I used the internal IP it would break things but it's actually the opposite. Using the exernal IP just confused Apache. Tell me if I'm wrong but I'm going to try that today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read @davidgo's comments above, they fixed my problem. Apparently, I was telling the server that the IP was 64.53.213.26 when it as really 192.168.1.39. Changing the address to the latter fixed the problem. One caveat I had to overcome was that I had checked the listen statement checkbox in Froxlor whilst changing the settings. It flashed an error at me that the address was already in use and I fixed that by getting rid of ports.conf, because it was telling the server to listen to 80 and 443 before the virtualhost did, and this confused it. I am going to change it though so that ports.conf is doing the listening and the virtualhost is not doing any listening. So, if you are changing the IPs in Froxlor DON'T check the listen box it will save you a lot of trouble. I guess that's it. Like I said read @davidgo's comments they are much more technical and might help you better.